# Triggering a Stock change externally with Restful or HTTP

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stock

I run a Woocommerce site, and I would like to trigger stock quantity changes via HTTP or via Restful API remotely.

I am asking because I run an e-commerce site, as well as a physical storefront, and I need them to talk to each other, and keep stock in sync.

How do I go about doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different possible approaches but it all depends on your POS system.

If it needs to be done via API you can write a controller to post to the inventory server, hooked in after hearing a success message from the payment gateway.